# R: Can't Download complete webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to read de following webpage with Rvest:

https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=147933

But I can't read it with Rvest, and Cant download it with Download.file.

When I try to download it all I get is an Html file with unreadable text.

My Code:

```
download_pag <- function(pag){
  download.file(site,"M.html",method = "auto",quiet = TRUE)
  return(1)
}

site <- 'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=153332'
download_pag(1)

link <- read_html('M.html')

html_text(html_nodes(link,'td'))
```

The result is Character(0), but the page has lots of contents

Comment: There are a number of issues: read_html can read the URL direct. So read_html(site) should work. No need to do the download thing normally.

Comment: But, let's back up a step. Is m.html empty? Is link empty?

Comment: The server wants an user agent header. Use httr.  e.g. `headers = c('User-Agent'='Mozilla/5.0')` and `r <- httr::GET(url = 'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=147933', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))`